# Insert Google Analytics' tracking code by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Analytics systems such as Google Analytics (GA) are very slow to load. Not only GA, but similar services (even Google Tag Manager). We consider this problem by the example of GA.

The idea is: catch mousemove, click or scroll events, wichever comes first. Then insert GA code after the target tlement.

I've prepared this script.

```
<div id="ma-code"></div>
<script>
    const addingLogic = ((alreadyAdded = false) => () => {
        if (alreadyAdded) return;        
        console.log('loading logic');
        let target = document.getElementById("ma-code");

        <!-- Insert Google Analytics tracking code here -->
        alreadyAdded = true;
    })();

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", addingLogic, { once: true });
    document.addEventListener("scroll", addingLogic, { once: true });
    document.addEventListener("click", addingLogic, { once: true });

    </script>
```

The script works (it prints to the console correctly).

Google Analytics' code looks like this:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-174-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-174-1');
</script>
```

**Problem**

I fail to insert it.

Could you help me?

By the way, my idea may be not ideal. If there is anything better,  that would also be interesting.